# how change background color in different pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i am two page in `reactjs`

pageOne.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./pageOne.css";
const PageOne = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      one
      <br />
      <Link to="/pageTwo">Two Page</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
export default PageOne;
```

pageTwo.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./pageTwo.css";
const PageTwo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      two
      <br />
      <Link to="/">One Page</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
export default PageTwo;
```

i am define two css files for change background color when page loaded.

pageOne.css

```
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke !important;
}
```

pageTwo.css

```
body {
  background-color: crimson !important;
}
```

it's problem.in `pageOne` background color is `crimson` and in `pageTwo` background color is `crimson`.

[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mccarthy-w4xjq?file=/src/pageTwo.css:27-34)

Comment: Well, you only got one `body` element in your whole DOM tree. So whatever comes last will override the previous ones.

Comment: thank you @SMAKSS.  How is the last page specified?

Comment: With the order of rendering. Your page two renders last so it will override the body colour.

Comment: How to meet this need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said earlier, there is only one `body` tag in the DOM tree by default. So when you try to style it whatever comes last will override the previous ones and in your case, the page two style will override the page one style.

To solve this, you got several options, but I will go with the easiest one. You can make a container for each of your pages and then assign a colour to that container to make the whole page background as you desired *(You can simply make a layout component then wrap each of the components within it and with similar approach make it reusable)*. So, for example, you can create your first page like this:

```html
<div className="crimson">
   two
   <br />
   <Link to="/">one Page</Link>
</div>
```

and style it like this:

```css
.crimson {
  background-color: crimson;
  min-height: 100vh; /* minimum height of page would be equal to available view-port height */
}
```

This goes the same for your other page. But you need to consider you have to remove the default margins from the `body` itself to prevent any disorder.

**Working Demo:**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: one question. And whether it is responsive page?

Comment: @A.R.SEIF Well, I’m not sure what do you asking but it will work for all page sizes.

Comment: The min-height solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this with Layout component:

```
const Layout = ({ backgroundColor = '#fff', children }) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor }} className="layout">
    {children}
  </div>
)
```

then remove your css(and try not to use **important** in your css)

```
<Layout backgroundColor="#fff"><PageOne /></Layout>
```

and

```
<Layout backgroundColor="#f00"><PageTwo /></Layout>
```

Comment: thank you. what's mean ```style={{ backgroundColor }}```?

Comment: backgroundColor - is a regular css property - background-color but in camelCase format which should be used in jsx. Actually you can apply style={{ background }} and it would work the same way

Comment: ok.i am change code in sample . please [review](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mccarthy-w4xjq?file=/src/layout.js)

Comment: yep, correct. I added some stylesheets [https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-waterfall-bg2ed?file=/src/styles.css]